# My font awesome icon isnt working when I use different class

Tags: html, fonts, icons

When I am using this

```
<i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

icon is appearing but when I am using this

```
<i class="far fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

its not working.
How can I solve this?
Note: those two icons are different.

Comment: It says [here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/referencing-icons/basic-use) that regular icons are not free...strange because I've used them before without any problems

Comment: Are you using the right CDN/source? This one: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css displays both styles correctly: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/marsnebulasoup/ovnLbyks/6/)

Comment: More CDNs here: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome

Comment: Whats the source? whete to find this source?

Comment: What do you mean? What source are you talking about?

Comment: CDN/source for far fa-user-circle @MarsNebulaSoup

Comment: I don't think there is a cdn for just one icon

Comment: You would have to search through the CSS file that the cdn provides

Answer (score 0):

Double check you're using the latest version of Font Awesome. If you're still using version 4, you'll need to upgrade to version 5 to use many icons.

E.g the 'far' regular prefix was introduced in version 5.

Details here: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/other-topics/troubleshooting